# Elasticsearch update mapping using json

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to change the type of a field from 'string' to 'date' (format: 'epoch_second' to be specific). Since there is no way to update the mappings of an existing index, I need to make a new index for which I mostly want to use the mapping from my existing index. Here is what I am using:

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/sam/saga/_mapping?pretty' >saga.json

to dump the mapping of the current index into a json file, the content of which is this:

```
{
  "sam" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "saga" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then I replace

```
         "name" : {
           "type" : "long"
         }
```

with

```
         "name" : {
           "type" : "date"
         }
```

and save the new file as saga2.json. then run this

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/sam/_mapping/saga2' -d @saga2.json

However, when I check the mapping of the new index, **all** types have changed to "string" now.

I even have this problem using the Elasticsearch's example.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: I found out that changing the type r format of a field does not work for different documents inside the same index. The solution would be to make a new index and give it the correct mapping by 1. PUT /new_index (make an index __without__ mapping) 2. PUT /new_index/_mapping/new_doc -d @new_mapping and then dump all the data from the old index to he new one and reindex them my the new mapping

Answer (score 1):

You need to make one more change in your `saga2.json` file, namely the mapping type name `saga` -> `saga2` (Now you probably need to rename it all to `saga3`

```
{
  "sam" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "saga2" : {                  <--- here
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "date"        <--- and here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then only you can run this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/sam/_mapping/saga2' -d @saga2.json
```